# Exact match string in panda column

Tags: python, string, pandas, match

**Set-up**

I scrape housing ad data and analyse with pandas. I have computed average statistics and inserted them in a pandas dataframe:  `district_df`.

One of the `district_df` columns contains district names: `district_df['district']`.

Another of the `district_df` columns contains subdistrict names: `district_df['subdistrict']`

They look like,

```
        district           subdistrict      
     Bergen-Enkheim      Bergen-Enkheim    
    Bornheim/Ostend            Bornheim
    Bornheim/Ostend              Ostend
            Harheim             Harheim
       Innenstadt I            Altstadt
       Innenstadt I     Bahnhofsviertel
       Innenstadt I              Gallus
      Innenstadt II          Bockenheim 
      Innenstadt II        Westend-Nord
                  ⋮                   ⋮
```

---

**Problem**

I create a district table (`district_table`) from `district_df` per district. I.e. for the above I create five district tables. I do this by the following code,

```
for district in d_set: # d_set is a set containing all district names 
    district_table = district_df[district_df['district'].str.match(district)]
```

This code works, that is: a table per district is created.

However, the table for `Innenstadt II` also contains the subdistricts of `Innenstadt I`.

It seems to me that `.str.match(district)` matches not exact, but partly. I.e. `Innenstadt I` will match `Innenstadt II`.

My actual `district_df` columns contain more then what I display here – issue occurs for a variety of district names.

How do I get exact matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) in loop:

```
d_set = district_df['district'].unique()

for district in d_set: 
    district_table = district_df[district_df['district'] == district]
    print (district_table)

         district     subdistrict
0  Bergen-Enkheim  Bergen-Enkheim
          district subdistrict
1  Bornheim/Ostend    Bornheim
2  Bornheim/Ostend      Ostend
  district subdistrict
3  Harheim     Harheim
       district      subdistrict
4  Innenstadt I         Altstadt
5  Innenstadt I  Bahnhofsviertel
6  Innenstadt I           Gallus
        district   subdistrict
7  Innenstadt II    Bockenheim
8  Innenstadt II  Westend-Nord
```

If need `dict` of `DataFrames` better is convert [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) object:

```
a = dict(tuple(district_df.groupby('district')))

print (a['Innenstadt I'])
       district      subdistrict
4  Innenstadt I         Altstadt
5  Innenstadt I  Bahnhofsviertel
6  Innenstadt I           Gallus
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be something stupidly easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it this way:

```
{ dist: df[df.district == dist] for dist in df.district.unique() }
```

But then again you might be better off using a MultiIndex:

```
df.set_index(['district', 'subdistrict'], inplace=True)
```

This is a lot like the `dict` solution, but downstream processing is likely to be faster.